# How to set server name in sql server using domain/path?

Tags: sql-server, docker, nginx, docker-compose, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have a sql-server running on a docker container in a vps.

this is how I ran the database using docker-compose:

```
version: "3"
services: 
    Parsa_DataBase:
        image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server
        environment: 
            ACCEPT_EULA: "Y"
            SA_PASSWORD: "password"
            MSSQL_PID: Express
        ports: 
            - 8083:1433
```

If I use the domain and port explicitly, it works, like this:

[image]

But I want to use domain/path in order to connect. Like this:

[image]

But it doesn't work:

[image]

Changing server name to `parsalotfy.ir/db, 443` didn't help

this is part of my nginx file :

```
# Database Location
location /db/ {
    proxy_set_header        Host                    $host;
    proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP               $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For         $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto       https;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8083;
}
```

Other locations of this nginx file work correctly such as /api/ and so on.

What is problem here and what should I do?

Thank you.

Comment: The problem is the "/db" has no meaning for a database connection because it is not a file location or url. The specified name just resolves to an IP address and the specified port for the TCP socket connection (which defaults to 1433 if not specified). Note SQL Server does not use the htttp protocol for client connections; it uses TDS.

Comment: so there is no way to route and wire the connection by nginx like 443-->8083 ? I should use the port explicitly?

Comment: I can't speak to nginx. I'm just saying the "/db" specification will not work with SSMS, AFAIK.